# coerce a function call into a string

Tags: r, callstack, coercion

I am trying to understand what is a `call` object in R and to coerce it to characters. However my efforts have been vain so far.

```
myFun=function(a=1) {   x=sys.call()   return(as.character(x)) }

x=myFun(a=2) # here I would like to get the string "myFun(a = 2)"
```

I have also been looking for the function that prints a function call (something like `print.call`). But I couldn't find it.

Does anybody here knows how call objects are printed?

Comment: There may be a simpler way, but `myFun <- function(a=1) { as.character(as.expression(sys.call())) }`

Comment: `as.expression` does the job, thank you @alistaire

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `match.call()` with `deparse`

```
myFun <- function(a=1) { 
            deparse(match.call())       
  }

myFun(a=2)
#[1] "myFun(a = 2)"
```

Or replace `match.call()` with `sys.call()` in the function